# Show different files from same folder

Tags: java, io, file-handling

I have folder which contains some files.I have 2 users.so,I want to show different files to both the users , but files are from the same folder. so, How can i do that ?

Comment: can you specify what mean different files? different based on file owner ?

Comment: There is one folder suggestion . In this folder different files are there , like A,B,C,D .So, now I have 2 users .Both of them are going to use the same files from the same folder . But, User 1 does not require A file , so, I don't want to show User 1 A file,while User B want to use that file ,so i want to show that file to user B.

Comment: How do you  distinguish between file needed to User1 and User2??you have a custom list of file name for the two user, or exist a rules ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) class that have information about the current users and will modify the files shown based on the user info.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFileChoosersetFileFilterFileFilterfilter.htm) an example.

You need to write your custom code in its accpet method.